# Row data into string conversion vb.net 2010

Tags: database, vb.net, string, row

How can I convert a row data into string or text and display it into a label? My problem is when I click on my login button which contains the SQL code that gains a row data into alabel, the result in my label is false. not the text. How can I convert it into string?

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmdLog_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdLog.Click
        Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim adaptor As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dataset As New DataSet
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
        Dim sapi
        sapi = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")

        connection.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Calupad\Desktop\HTF feat Yiyet\HTF feat Yiyet\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE Username='" & txtUser.Text & "' AND Password ='" & txtPass.Text & "';"
        txtWel.Text = "Welcome Back, " + txtUser.Text + "!....."


        connection.Open()
        command.Connection = connection
        adaptor.SelectCommand = command
        adaptor.Fill(dataset, "0")

        txtStat.text = command.CommandText = "SELECT Status FROM [Users] WHERE Username = '" & txtUser.Text & "' ".ToString

        txtStat.Text = stat
                Dim count = dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        If count > 0 Then

            MsgBox("Login Successful!" & vbNewLine & txtStat.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Access Granted")
            sapi.speak(txtWel.Text)
            Me.Hide()
            Form1.Show()
            frmMenu.Show()
            txtUser.Clear()
            txtPass.Clear()
            tries = 3
        Else
            ctr = tries - 1
            tries = ctr
            sapi.speak(txtUser.Text + txtNot.Text)
            MsgBox("Invalid Account!" + vbNewLine + "Attempts Remaining: " & tries, vbCritical, "Access Denied")
            txtUser.Clear()
            txtPass.Clear()
            If tries = 0 Then
                MsgBox("You've reached the maximum attempts!" + vbNewLine + "The program will be terminated.", vbCritical, "Terminated!")
                Me.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: what is `stat` here: `txtStat.Text = stat`? We can't see it declared anywhere in the code

Comment: stat is my variable for string :) i already declared it

Comment: i'll paste my code again here . wait :)

Comment: the declaration was not placed in the login button and the sql connection and command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the way you check for username and password is weak and is most certainly volnurable to SQL injections. You are checking if the 'count' of rows is greater than zero then the user has logged in successfully, where as you should only compare `count` to 1. and instead of counting the rows, try to compare the row values to what the user has input in the username and passoword fields and what is returned from the database rows.

The "hacker" can simply type this and he will be allowed to log in according to the logic of your code:

[image: SQL INJECTION]

You just need to retrieve the data stored into `dataset` variable that you filled using the adapter.

Assuming your database table contains fields like `First_Name` and 'Last_Name', here is how you can display them on any label control on your form:

```
adaptor.Fill(dataset, "0")
myFirstName.Text = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("First_Name").ToString()
myLastName.Text = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("First_Name").ToString()
```

You can also retrieve the column without having to know its name like this

```
myLabel.text = = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3).ToString() 
    'This will retrieve the 4th column from the table (zero based array)
```

You can also clean up your code by declaring a variable to hold the retrieved table

```
adaptor.Fill(dataset, "0")
Dim myTable as DataTable = dataset.Tables(0)
myFirstName.Text = myTable.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you but, what i wanted to do is to get the status that is equal to the User that logs in , the status was already stored in the table in the database which has 3 column the Username,Password, and the Status .

Comment: @user3172293 I modified my answer to warn you about SQL injection. Where is the declaration of the state variable?

Comment: thank you for the help , the code worked well :) god bless thank you ... really!!

Comment: @user3172293 have you modified your code to avoid the SQL injection as I have described in my modified answer?